# How to send emails back via moneris upon successful purchase?

Tags: php, api, credit-card, onlinebanking

The company I work for has a method for processing credit cards. The only thing is... there seems to be ZERO api incorporated within the webpages. We use Moneris. All I see is this:

```
<?php
$monerisURL = ($debug) ? "https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php" : "https://www3.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php";

?>    
<form name="mail" action="<?php echo $monerisURL; ?>" method="post">
<?php
```

That's fine as it seems to work (I don't understand why but it does). Furthermore, the person who was here before me was actually a graphic artist (and NOT a programmer, so the way he programmed a lot of shit is confusing like crazy to me). In any case, I have never set up any moneris or other credit card payment solution methods.

I've been searching online to understand how it works, and the closest thing I found was this link:

https://github.com/ironkeith/Moneris-eSELECTplus-API/blob/master/examples/purchase.php

But, it is extremely extremely far from what the graphic artist did. So different.
In any case, the problem I am having is simply adding an email address (for the client and for us). Since the email acts in this case as a proof of purchase, it cannot come before the client makes a purchase. The email which is sent must come AFTER a successful transaction.

There is another place where I had to modify the coding (since his coding wasn't working), and so now I can properly send emails (the same as mentioned before) to clients who are making purchases via ANOTHER method. So now, all I need to figure out is how to send an email in conjunction to moneris. I've looked through the files, and found nothing resembling an api of any sort. Nor any file itself that would be exclusively reserved for the purpose of using Moneris.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there seemed to be a login (which I was completely unaware of until this morning). Since I couldn't find anything, I suspected it would have been something of the genre.